# How to position views near the screen edges using Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to change my GridLayout to the ConstraintLayout.

My grid looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_asset"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:skipStartColor="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_asset"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="1"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    android:text="text text text" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_sync"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_row="0"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:skipStartColor="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_sync"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_row="1"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    android:text="text text text" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_completed"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="3"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:skipStartColor="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_completed"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="4"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    android:text="@string/msg_in_store_commissioning_stage_completed" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_params"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"

    app:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_row="3"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:skipStartColor="true"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

And it produces the output like this:

[image]

I am new to ConstraintLayout. Is there an easy way to accomplish the same behaviour using Constraint Layout? I guess it will be more efficient and clean.

Using RelativeLayout will be just to align left, right, bottom etc.
Using LinearLayout will be just to put some empty view in between those Circular views and add the specific weights to them.

But how it can be easly done with ConstraintLayout?

UPDATE:
Here is what i tried with ConstraintLayout so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_asset"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text text text"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_row="1" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"

    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_sync"
    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text text text"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_stage_completed"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_medium"

    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"


    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_completed"

    style="@style/AppWidget.Text.Emphasized"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/msg_in_store_commissioning_stage_completed"
    android:textColor="@color/circular_progress_middle_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_completed"
    app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.app.widget.CircularColorProgressView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_color_progress_size_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:hideText="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:skipStartColor="true" />
```

It produces pretty similiar to the Grid:
[image]

Comment: Please share what you tried with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: please share your CircularColorProgressView file also

Comment: @RamiJemli I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy if you use design editor in android studio for accomplishing this.

Add `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` as Parent in your view

**>     To align a view in top - left**

```
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

**To align a view in top-right**

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

**To align a view in bottom-left**

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

**To align a view in bottom-right**

```
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

**To align a view to below of another view (in your case the TextView)**

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewId"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_asset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text text text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/progress_stage_asset"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_asset" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text text text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/progress_stage_sync"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/progress_stage_sync"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_stage_sync"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_stage_completed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progress_text_stage_completed"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progress_text_stage_completed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/progress_stage_completed"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/progress_stage_completed"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_stage_params"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```